# Android Studio - different device screen layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am suffering!!!

Using latest version of Android Studio, I am developing a app and suffering with the screen layout on devices.

For example, running on Nexus 5, the screen and position of TextView, ImageView and Buttons is perfect. But running on Galaxy S5, it looks different, the objects are not on the same place as on Nexus 5.

I have tried to make layout based on density - creating the screen for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi - or based on Size - screen for normal, large and x-large, but nothing works like desired.

In any of both cases the same screen layout is called (for example xxhdpi) from Nexus 5 as from Galaxy S5, but the layout is different.

What am I doing wrong or overseeing?

**EDIT:**

Just to make it more clear. [image]

This is the screen I want to develop. There are 8 TextViews (white spaces) on it, and in the lower part two buttons.

Depending on the Android device, the texts are upper or below the white spaces.

This is the XML that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#888888">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:background="@drawable/registro"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfUsername"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="USUARIO"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="CONTRASEÑA"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tfUsername"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tfPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:hint="CONFIRMAR CONTRASEÑA"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfMail"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="CORREO ELECTRONICO"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="CONFIRMAR CORREO "
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tfMail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tfConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfMonth"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="MM"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tfDay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfYear"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="AAAA"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tfMonth"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tfMonth"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tfMonth" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tfDay"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hint="DD"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tfMonth"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tfConfirmMail"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:onClick="selSignUp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnBirthday"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:onClick="showDate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tfMonth"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnTerminos"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sizing and positioning your views with "px" dimmensions instead of "dp"?

Comment: No, all is in "dp". I think that I have found something. It is related that in the  design screen I have on the bottom hardware buttons. I have done a screen for Galaxy 3, without the hardware buttons and it looks perfect on the device and is the same as the design.

Comment: But how can I delete these hardware buttons for other devices? I tried to make a new 1080x1920 device, but the hardware buttons are still there.